# Python: NameError after introduction of if-clause

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am appending columns of .csv files to a list of pandas Dataframe/Series objects with the following code

```
process_time_dfs = []
status_dfs = []

for string in filestrings:
    
    #read in command with apropriate delimiter and engine starting from a nmc-specific line in the excel doc
    EIS_TS_csv = pd.read_csv(DATA_DIR.joinpath(string), engine = 'python', delimiter = ';', skiprows = startposition)

    #drop [descriptor] row
    EIS_TS_csv.drop(index = 0, axis = 0, inplace = True)

    #add to dataframe
    status_dfs.append(EIS_TS_csv['Status'])
    process_time_dfs.append(EIS_TS_csv['Progr. Zeit'].str.replace('.', '').astype(float))
```

This code works fine for most of the .csv files but not for some specific files since in them the column `'Progr. Zeit'`does not contain string objects. So I thought I could adapt the code to this circumstance with an if-clause:

```
process_time_dfs = []
status_dfs = []

for string in filestrings:
    
    #read in command with apropriate delimiter and engine starting from a nmc-specific line in the excel doc
    EIS_TS_csv = pd.read_csv(DATA_DIR.joinpath(string), engine = 'python', delimiter = ';', skiprows = startposition)

    #drop [descriptor] row
    EIS_TS_csv.drop(index = 0, axis = 0, inplace = True)

    #add to dataframe
    status_dfs.append(EIS_TS_csv['Status'])
    
    if EIS_TS_csv['Progr. Zeit'].dtype == object:
        process_time_dfs.append(EIS_TS_csv['Progr. Zeit'].str.replace('.', '').astype(float))
    else:
        process_time_dfs.append(EIS_TS_csv['Progr. Zeit'].astype(float))
```

It seems to me like a small change that should work just fine but it produces this error:

```
>>> process_time_dfs.append(EIS_TS_csv['Progr. Zeit'].str.replace('.', '').astype(float))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'process_time_dfs' is not defined
```

And I have no idea how that could have come to pass since the list whose name is not recognized is defined in the same way as before. Please help me understand what went wrong here!

Comment: I noticed that there's a `>>>` in your output, which means you're running in Python's interactive mode. Is it possible you didn't paste the Python code for the variable declarations first? Can you run it out of a python file instead?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the way you type the paths.

```
path = r'/usr/local/bin/python3 "/Users/gnthr/Desktop/EISTSAnalysisCalendric.py"'
```

I just added path to make it a variable for you. I do not know what you are trying to accomplish with this.